# How to connect one model variable to mutiple html elements using angularjs data binding?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to write some application using `ng-repeat` and `limitTo`, but it seems that the input field and the buttons can't work together on the same model value.

The problem is that once I changed the value from the `input field`, the `buttons` won't work any more. could you tell me why?

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        'Jani',
        'Carl',
        'Margareth',
        'Hege',
        'Joe',
        'Gustav',
        'Birgit',
        'Mary',
        'Kai'
    ];
    $scope.test = 3;
    $scope.dPlus = function(){
       $scope.test++;
    }
    $scope.dMinus = function(){
       $scope.test--;
    }
    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

<div ng-if='true'>

<p>Type a number in the input field:</p>

<p><input type="number" ng-model="test"></p>
<input type="button" value="+" ng-click="dPlus()"/>
<input type="button" value="-" ng-click="dMinus()"/>
<div>{{ test }}</div>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names | limitTo:test">
    {{ x }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you bind value directly in ng-model. Put it in some object and it will work just fine. Like this:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="vm.counter">
```

https://www.toptal.com/angular-js/top-18-most-common-angularjs-developer-mistakes

Mistake #2 :)

Comment: It is exactly what I want, Thanks ! : )

Comment: But remember that @Olezt is actually right! Stick to using "controller as" syntax, since it helps in many ways. Most obvious one is the possibility to use ES6 classes smoothly for your controllers, and use inheritance for them. Isn't that neat?

Comment: Yeah, "controller as" syntax is a better solution as `Common Mistake #3: Not Using controllerAs Syntax` & `Common Mistake #4: Not Fully Utilising The controllerAs Syntax` specified.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `controller as` syntax and it works.

> If the model is a primitive, the child scope will just create a new
>   model. But if the change is to a property of a model object, the
>   lookup on parent scopes will find the referenced object and change its
>   actual property. [Common Mistake #2: Not Having a Dot In There](https://www.toptal.com/angular-js/top-18-most-common-angularjs-developer-mistakes)

Here is the working code:

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function() {

var vm = this;
    
vm.names = [
        'Jani',
        'Carl',
        'Margareth',
        'Hege',
        'Joe',
        'Gustav',
        'Birgit',
        'Mary',
        'Kai'
    ];
    vm.test = 3;


    vm.dPlus = function(){
       vm.test++;
    }
    vm.dMinus = function(){
       vm.test--;
    }
    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl as vm">

<div ng-if='true'>

<p>Type a number in the input field:</p>

<p><input type="number" ng-model="vm.test"></p>
<input type="button" value="+" ng-click="vm.dPlus()"/>
<input type="button" value="-" ng-click="vm.dMinus()"/>
<div>{{ vm.test }}</div>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in vm.names | limitTo:vm.test">
    {{ x }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>

<p>The list will only consists of names matching the filter.</p>

</body>
</html>
```